# Как генерировать индивидуальный счёт на оплату для каждого пользователя? QiwiP2P TeleBot Telegram

Tags: telegram, telebot, qiwi, p2p, pyqiwi

Как сделать так чтоб для каждого пользователя создавался собственный new_bill при нажатии на кнопку 'ОПЛАТИТЬ' ?
В данном коде, в самом боте создаётся счёт и он работает для всех юзеров.

```
from pyqiwip2p import QiwiP2P

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    menu2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    if call.data == 'first':
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
        menu2.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='ОПЛАТИТЬ' ,callback_data='oplata'))
        menu2.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='НАЗАД', callback_data='back'))
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='Тариф: Первый', reply_markup=menu2)     
    if call.data == 'oplata':
        new_bill = p2p.bill(bill_id=rand, amount=70, lifetime=3)
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, call.message.message_id)
        menu2.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='✅ПЕРЕЙТИ К ОПЛАТЕ: Qiwi/RU карта', url=(new_bill.pay_url), callback_data='oplata5'))
        menu2.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='ОТМЕНА', callback_data='back'))
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text= '✅ Счёт на оплату сформирован.Доступ к приватным материалам будет открыт, как только вы оплатите его.',reply_markup=menu2)
```

Comment: p2p = “QIWI secret token”

Answer (score 1):

Отредактировал ваш код, вы забыли добавить **секретный ключ QIWI**

```
from pyqiwip2p import QiwiP2P

p2p = QiwiP2P(auth_key='SECRET KEY QIWI')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    menu2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    if call.data == 'first':
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
        menu2.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='ОПЛАТИТЬ' ,callback_data='oplata'))
        menu2.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='НАЗАД', callback_data='back'))
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text='Тариф: Первый', reply_markup=menu2)
    if call.data == 'oplata':
        new_bill = p2p.bill(bill_id=rand, amount=70, lifetime=3)
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, call.message.message_id)
        menu2.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='✅ПЕРЕЙТИ К ОПЛАТЕ: Qiwi/RU карта', url=(new_bill.pay_url), callback_data='oplata5'))
        menu2.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='ОТМЕНА', callback_data='back'))
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text= '✅ Счёт на оплату сформирован.Доступ к приватным материалам будет открыт, как только вы оплатите его.',reply_markup=menu2)
```

Comment: Я не забыл его вставить, я его просто не вставил в вопрос. А сам вопрос заключается в другом: "Как генерировать индивидуальный счёт на оплату для каждого пользователя?"

Comment: ```new_bill = p2p.bill(bill_id=rand, amount=70, lifetime=3)``` в данной переменной содержится индивидуальный счёт на оплату